# Can't set my grid card content to equal height

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want all cards in my grid to have equal height. I've been trying for hours with chrome, testing various combinations but I can't achieve the desired result. I want the content part of the card (pink) to expand so that everything is in the same line.

Grid cells are perfect. But if I flex grow the card or set it to 100% height, it fills the grid item (which is shown in picture 1) with paper (picture 2). I did the same thing for all the children (especially the text area), but they won't expand.

Tried stretching, changing displays, heights etc. Want to avoid a fixed height (even dependent on viewport) or fixed max height at all costs. Any ideas?

[image: This image shows the grid element padding around the card]

[image: What happens when I flex grow or set height 100% in the card]

Edit: Maybe it's worth mentioning that the closest I've gotten to the desired result is setting `display: content` at the `CardActionArea` sub-element. Card is exactly as I want it except that it pushes my text at the bottom.

Here's the code of my styles and my first card - I'll leave the comments in to show some of the things that have been tried and tested (some code is also irrelevant but I'll leave it in in case something sabotages what I'm trying to do):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  grid: {}, //grid works exactly as I want it
  gridItem: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
      padding: "32px !important"
    }
    // display: "flex",
    // flexDirection: "column",
    // justifyContent: "space-between",
    // alignItems: "stretch"
    // [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
    //   padding: theme.spacing(0)
    // }
  },
  card: {
    "&:hover": {
      boxShadow:
        "0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.23)",
      // margin: "-10px auto 0",
      // transform: "scale(1.01)",
      // boxShadow: "-6px 4px 3px rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.2)",
      // top: "-4px",
      transition: ["boxShadow", "margin"],
      transitionDuration: 300
    },
    display: "flex",
    flexFlow: "column"
    // flexDirection: "column",
    // justifyContent: "space-between",
    // alignItems: "stretch",
    // height: "100%"

    // maxWidth: "300px",
    // maxHeight: 345
    // boxShadow:
    //   "10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.43)"
    // display: "block",
    // width: "100%",
  },
  media: {
    height: "auto",
    width: "100%",
    objectFit: "cover"
    // margin: "-70px auto 0",
    // width: "80%",
    // height: 140,
    // borderRadius: "4px",
    // boxShadow: "0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23)",
    // position: "relative",
    // zIndex: 1000
  },
  content: {
    background: "linear-gradient(to right, #ee9ca7, #ffdde1)",
    padding: "10px",
    flexGrow: 1
    // display: "flex"
    // flexDirection: "column",
    // justifyContent: "space-between",
    // alignItems: "stretch",
    // height: "100%"
  },
  contHead: {
    color: "black",
    marginBottom: "3px"
  },
  contText: {
    color: "black"
  },
  buttonArea: {
    background: "linear-gradient(to right, #000000, #434343)",

    // display: "flex", //card has flex by default
    flexFlow: "wrap",
    justifyContent: "center",
    padding: "0"
  },
  buttons: {
    // backgroundColor: "white",
    padding: "0",
    minHeight: "29px",
    marginLeft: "0 !important",
    marginTop: "5px",
    marginBottom: "5px"
  },
  icons: { color: "white", fontSize: "1.8rem" },
  iconsTBA: { color: "#9c7e82", fontSize: "1.3rem" },
  toolTips: {
    // backgroundColor: "#f5f5f9",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
    maxWidth: 350,
    // // maxHeight: 100,
    fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(14),
    // border: "1px solid #dadde9",
    // // transform: "translate(100px, 200px) rotate(50deg)"
    // // transform: "translate(50%,90%)"
    // marginLeft: "23vw",
    // marginTop: "90vh",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
      marginBottom: "35vh"
    }
  },
  toolTipsCard: {
    fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(20)
  }
}));

//Tooltip info
const rpgTT = "test";

const Games = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className="full-container-2">
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid className={classes.grid} container spacing={3}>
          <Grid className={classes.gridItem} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={4}>
            <Card className={classes.card}>
              <Tooltip
                classes={{ tooltip: classes.toolTipsCard }}
                TransitionComponent={Zoom}
                title="Play"
                placement="top"
              >
                <CardActionArea>
                  <CardMedia className={classes.media} image={pic1} />
                  <CardContent className={classes.content}>
                    <Typography
                      className={classes.contHead}
                      gutterBottom
                      variant="h5"
                      component="h2"
                    >
                      Game Title
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography
                      className={classes.contText}
                      variant="body2"
                      color="textSecondary"
                      component="p"
                    >
                      This is a small string
                    </Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                </CardActionArea>
              </Tooltip>
              <CardActions className={classes.buttonArea}>
                <Button className={classes.buttons}>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                    title="Not Available Yet"
                    className={classes.iconsTBA}
                    icon={faWindows}
                  />
                </Button>
                <Button className={classes.buttons}>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                    title="Not Available Yet"
                    className={classes.iconsTBA}
                    icon={faLinux}
                  />
                </Button>
                <Button className={classes.buttons}>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon className={classes.icons} icon={faGithub} />
                </Button>

                <Tooltip
                  classes={{ tooltip: classes.toolTips }}
                  TransitionComponent={Zoom}
                  title={rpgTT}
                  placement="bottom"
                >
                  <Button className={classes.buttons}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon
                      className={classes.icons}
                      icon={faInfoCircle}
                    />
                  </Button>
                </Tooltip>
              </CardActions>
            </Card>
          </Grid>
```

Comment: try using `display: flex` on container and play around with `align-content`

Comment: Already tried setting display: flex to everything, adding flex direction, flex grow etc, and tried all possible combinations of align/justify content/items for all the grid children (grid items to card content text areas).

Comment: It would be great not only having images in your question, but your code as well so people can easily play around with it and help you. Peeps are too lazy to analyze your code from images :(

Comment: I normally would but in this case I thought showing one of the settings combinations I have tried wouldn't do much difference. Will add my styles in a bit.

Comment: Try this set `display: flex` to the container that holds all cards and then to card itself set `display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%`

Comment: No luck with that unfortunately :/ Also tried set these settings to my text content and other card sub-elements. Thank you for trying to help, uploaded my code too but it's a bloated mess I'm afraid.

Comment: Now I think I got it. The element that is highlighted on your pic does actually have the same height with other elements. Try going one element deep (to the next nested element) and check it's height. And if its not 100% set it to be so

Comment: Exactly. The element in the 1st picture is the grid item, direct container of the card, and it has the right size. However, when I try to set the card (it's next nested element) to height 100% or make it flex grow, it does grow (its paper), but its contents don't, as it is shown in the 2nd picture (white space). After than, I tried doing the same thing with all other children (even cardactionareas) but the content just won't scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the culprit.** It was the `CardActionArea` (a subcomponent of the card that make it clickable and contains the ripple effect of MUI).

The desired result is achieved only when this area has all of the following properties, so that the content fits into that area:

```
flexGrow: 1,
display: "flex",
flexDirection: "column",
alignItems: "stretch"
```

Thanks to everyone for discussing it, helped me approach the problem in a better way and started commenting out the sub-elements of the card one by one and found the problem. Cheers!

Comment: To stick the button to the bottom, I needed to set flexDirection to "column-reverse".

Answer (score 1):

Make each card a flexbox and give the info panel a `flex-grow: 1`:

```css
.grid{
   display:grid;
       grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.card {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.card img{
 width: 100%;
}

.card .info{
  background-color: pink;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
    <div class="info">
       <h1>Title</h1>
       <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
    <div class="info">
       <h1>Title</h1>
       <p>Text</p>
       <p>Text</p>
       <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Wish I could say that it works :/ Grid behaves perfectly in general, the grid cells have just the right size. And the card component does expand as shown in pic 2, but only its paper element expands. Tried setting flex display and grow to all other sub-elements too but they won't budge.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to achieve wanted card behavior in a very simple way, I hope that would help:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
    border: 4px solid #827d7d;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 8px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.card_header {
  background-color: grey;
}

.card_content {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}

h1, p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card_header">
      <h1>I'm header</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card_content">
      <p>I'm different amount of content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card_header">
      <h1>I'm header</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card_content">
      <p>I'm different amount of content</p>
      <p>I'm different amount of content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card_header">
      <h1>I'm header</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card_content">
      <p>I'm different amount of content</p>
      <p>I'm different amount of content</p>
      <p>I'm different amount of content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card_header">
      <h1>I'm header</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card_content">
      <p>I'm different amount of content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card_header">
      <h1>I'm header</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card_content">
      <p>I'm different amount of content</p>
      <p>I'm different amount of content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card_header">
      <h1>I'm header</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card_content">
      <p>I'm different amount of content</p>
      <p>I'm different amount of content</p>
      <p>I'm different amount of content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: These examples work but I am afraid that something in the hierarchy with the card MUI element causes the problem. Hierarchy is something like that = grid -> grid item -> Card -> Tooltip -> Card Action Area, Card Actions. CAA contains the media and content, which contains header and text. Card Actions contain the buttons and icons. I'll try to remove elements and find what is going wrong.